# It crashes in cellforrowatindexpath of tableview , says : "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have two tableview on the same Collectionviewcell. When I run the application, it crashes in cellforrowatindexpath of tableview , says : "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Please find below some of my code -

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> 
UITableViewCell {

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:     
reuseIdentifier, for: indexPathOfCollectionView as IndexPath) as!   
MyCustomCollectionViewCell

if(tableView == cell.graphTableView){

let cell:CustomGraphTableViewCell =   
tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomGraphTableViewCell") as!    
CustomGraphTableViewCell

return cell
    }
    else
    {
        let cell:MyCustomTableViewCell = 
 tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCustomTableViewCell") as!   
 MyCustomTableViewCell
        cell.nameLabel.text = namesArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell

    }
}
```

Can anyone please suggest the solution. Why is it happening and what can be the solution for the same?

Comment: You cannot dequeue `CollectionViewCell`` in TableView `cellForRowAt` method.

Comment: you make force unwrap here "as!" check your all cells, because now its nil

Comment: @NiravD Any idea then how can I access the tableview if I don't declare the collectionview cell there?

Comment: @Vadim Kozak Ok. If its nil, what can I do to correct it?

Comment: Why you are using collectionview cell instead of tableview cell? collectionview cell won't work in tableview as cell.

Comment: Hi @AbhishekMitra I need to check which tableview is working in cellforrowatindexath. How  can U handle that?

Comment: You are using two tableViews,  That's fine, but where are you using those tableview?? According to your question, you are using it in Collectionview's cell, it's sound little weird to me. And why do u need that tableViews in CollectionViews cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In tableview `UICollectionViewCell` won't work, `UICollectionViewCell` is different class which is inherited from `UICollectionReusableView` and `UITableViewCell` is a different class from `UICollectionViewCell` and it is inherited from `UIView`, `NSCoding`, `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`, so here, you have to use only uitableview cell for your tableview. Else it will crash.

When your tableview delegate method return some value not but null or 0, then datasource method of tableview will execute, that means when your tableview's delegate method have some value the

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> 
UITableViewCell
```

above method will now started executing and when it found

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:     
reuseIdentifier, for: indexPathOfCollectionView as IndexPath) as!   
MyCustomCollectionViewCell
```

above statement, it will get crashed.

This is

```
let cell:MyCustomTableViewCell = 
 tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCustomTableViewCell") as!   
 MyCustomTableViewCell
        cell.nameLabel.text = namesArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
```

only put this statement under the cellforRow datasource method, it will work accordingly.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Abhishek! Yes I removed the collectionviewcell object from cellforrowatindexpath and assigned the tag to tableview for check and now it is working fine :)

Comment: Great, :) Happy Codding, if my suggestion worked for you then please accept and up vote my answer.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this line

```
cell.nameLabel.text = namesArray[indexPath.row]
```

The `cell.nameLabel` is always accept string value, first convert into string value like this:

```
cell.nameLabel.text = namesArray[indexPath.row] as NSString
```